# Uploading files using Ajax failed

Tags: php, file-upload, upload

I've done a litte script without Ajax to upload files, when I added Ajax, it does not work, when I checked the result, I found there is no $_FILES data submitted:

form.php

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" dir="rtl">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />  

<script type="text/javascript" src="../JS/jquery.js"></script>


<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function(){

function readURL(input) {
    if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
        var reader = new FileReader();

        reader.onload = function (e) {
            $('#prevElem').attr('src', e.target.result);
        }

        reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
    }
}

$("#imgInp").change(function(){
    readURL(this);

    // get natural (local) image height
    //var naturalH = document.querySelector('img#prevElem').naturalHeight;
    var naturalH = $('img#prevElem').height();
    alert(naturalH);
    $("span.imgH").append(naturalH);
    // get natural (local) image width
    var naturalW = document.querySelector('img#prevElem').naturalWidth;
    $("span.imgW").append(naturalW);

});


$('.submitFile').click(function(){


        var getData = $('.formUp').serialize();
        console.log(getData);
        var dataString = getData;
        //console.log(dataString);


    $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "upload.php",
    enctype: 'multipart/form-data',
    data: dataString,
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(data) {

         alert(data);

    } // end function
        }); // end ajax

    return false;
    });

});
</script>

</head>

<body>

<fieldset style="width: 700px; margin-right: auto; margin-left: auto; border-width: 0px;">

<form name="formUp" class="formUp" method="POST" action="upload.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">

<input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="10000000" />

<input type='file' name="fileToUpload" id="imgInp" />
    <br>
    <div style="text-align: center;">
    <img id="prevElem" src="../Images/logo.png" />
    </div>
    Width : <span class="imgW"></span>
    <br />
    Height : <span class="imgH"></span>
<ul>

<li style="list-style: none;">
<span style="margin-right: 2em;">
<input type="submit" name="Send" class="submitFile" value="GO" />
</span>
<br />
</li>
</ul>
</form>
</fieldset>
  </body>
</html>
```

upload.php

```
<?php

print_r($_POST);

echo '<br />';
echo '<br />';

print_r($_FILES);

$fileToUpload = $_POST['fileToUpload'];

echo 'file '.$fileToUpload.'<br />';

$target_file = time();

if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {
    echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]). " has been uploaded.";
} else {
    echo "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
}

?>
```

The result of the print_r is:

```
Array
(
[MAX_FILE_SIZE] => 10000000
)
<br /><br />Array
(
)
file <br />Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.
```

Thanks for your usual support

**EDIT**

I got it solved, the solution is:

form.php:

```
// serialize() will not work to get the file property
// formatage is the form id
        var fullData = new FormData(document.getElementById("formatage")); // formatage is the form id

// since we have the form information, and the variable "act" is not included in the form, we can append it to the form, first act is the property and the second one is the variable

        fullData.append('act', act);

    $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "Check.php",        
    enctype: 'multipart/form-data',
    contentType: false,
    processData: false,
    data: fullData,
    dataType: "json",

    success: function(data) {
// do some stuff here
```

upload.php

```
<?php

$ImageType      = $_FILES['fileToUpload']['type']; //"image/png", image/jpeg etc.
$ImageTmp       = $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"];
$ImageSize      = $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["size"];
$ImageError     = $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["error"];

echo 'type '.$ImageType.'<br />';
echo 'tmp '.$ImageTmp.'<br />';
echo 'size '.$ImageSize.'<br />';
echo 'error '.$ImageError.'<br />';

$imginfo_array = getimagesize($ImageTmp);
print_r($imginfo_array);
// sample output:

/* Array
(
[0] => 642
[1] => 389
[2] => 3
[3] => width="642" height="389"
[bits] => 8
[mime] => image/png
)
*/

$target_file = time().'.png';

if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {
    echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]). " has been uploaded.";
} else {
   echo "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
}

?>
```